# manhattan distance heuristic in n puzzle python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, sliding-tile-puzzle

I have a problem with my function that calculates the manhattan distance for the 8-puzzle in python. My code have a problem especially with a particular state: [4,3,7,5,8,6,1,0,2] ,(on some other state I tried it and it worked..) my code runs but doesn't stop running and doesn't print the result then I don't know where the problem is in my function.

The code I run:

```
def search(n):
    s=[[4,3,7,5,8,6,1,0,2],""]
    print(s)
    f=frontier.create(s)
    while not frontier.is_empty(f):
        s=frontier.remove(f)
        if state.is_target(s):
            return [s, f[1], f[3]]
        ns=state.get_next(s)
        for i in ns:
            frontier.insert(f,i)
    return 0


print(search(3))
```

My function that calculates the Manhattan distance:

```
def hdistance(s):
    # the heuristic value of s
    i = 0 #represent the row number
    j = 0 #represent the column number
    sum = 0 #the manhattan distance
    n = math.sqrt(len(s[0])) #calculate the size of the n puzzle
    for k in s[0]: #run through the list
        if k != 0:
            row = int(k / n)
            column = int(k % n)
            sum = sum + abs(i - row) + abs(j - column)
            j += 1 #increment the column
            if j == n: #if I get to the end of the line
                i += 1 #increment the row
                j = 0
    return sum #return the manhattan distance
```

The frontier file:

```
def create(s):
    return [[s], 0, 0 ,0]


def is_empty(f):
    return f[0]==[]

def val(s):
    return state.hdistance(s)+state.path_len(s)

# Uniform Cost: return state.path_len(s)
# Greedy Best First: return state.hdistance(s)

def insert(h, s):
    #inserts state s to the frontier
    f=h[0]
    h[1]+=1
    h[2]+=1
    if h[2]>h[3]:
        h[3]=h[2]
    f.append(s)
    i=len(f)-1
    while i>0 and val(f[i])<val(f[(i-1)//2]):
        t=f[i]
        f[i]=f[(i-1)//2]
        f[(i-1)//2]=t
        i=(i-1)//2

def remove(h):
    if is_empty(h):
        return 0
    h[2]-=1
    f=h[0]
    s=f[0]
    f[0]=f[len(f)-1]
    del f[-1]
    heapify(f,0)
    return s

def heapify(f,i):
    minSon=i
    if 2*i+1<len(f) and val(f[2*i+1])<val(f[minSon]):
        minSon=2*i+1
    if 2*i+2<len(f) and val(f[2*i+2])<val(f[minSon]):
        minSon=2*i+2
    if minSon!=i:
        t=f[minSon]
        f[minSon]=f[i]
        f[i]=t
        heapify(f, minSon)
```

The state file:

```
def get_next(x):            # returns a list of the children states of x
    ns=[]                   # the next state list
    for i in "<>v^":
        s=x[0][:]           # [:] - copies the board in x[0]
        if_legal(s,i)       # try to move in direction i
        # checks if the move was legal and...
        if s.index(0)!=x[0].index(0) and \
           (x[1]=="" or x[1][-1]!="><^v"["<>v^".index(i)]): # check if it's the first move or it's a reverse move
            ns.append([s,x[1]+i])   # appends the new state to ns
    return ns


def path_len(x):
    return len(x[1])

def is_target(x):
    n=len(x[0])                     # the size of the board
    return x[0]==list(range(n))     # list(range(n)) is the target state

#############################
def if_legal(x,m):                  # gets a board and a move and makes the move if it's legal
    n=int(math.sqrt(len(x)))        # the size of the board is nXn
    z=x.index(0)                    # z is the place of the empty tile (0)
    if z%n>0 and m=="<":            # checks if the empty tile is not in the first col and the move is to the left
        x[z]=x[z-1]                 # swap x[z] and x[z-1]...
        x[z-1]=0                    # ...and move the empty tile to the left
    elif z%n<n-1 and m==">":        # check if the empty tile is not in the n's col and the move is to the right
        x[z]=x[z+1]
        x[z+1]=0
    elif z>=n and m=="^":           # check if the empty tile is not in the first row and the move is up
        x[z]=x[z-n]
        x[z-n]=0
    elif z<n*n-n and m=="v":        # check if the empty tile is not in the n's row and the move is down
        x[z]=x[z+n]
        x[z+n]=0
```

The rest of the code (all the other functions) are given in my assignment then the problem is certainly in my hdistance function.
If you could find where the problem is in my function, maybe there is an infinite loop...
Thank u!!

Comment: Put in some `print` calls so you know what it's doing.

Comment: Please provide more code on `frontier` and `state`. The `search` function is undecipherable without this. What is the input to the `hdistance` function? How are `hdistance` and `search` even related? There are too many unknowns here for someone to provide an accurate and helpful answer.

Comment: Also, sum is an inbuilt python function, you should not use it as a variable name.

Comment: Yes you're right, I just added the rest of the code @thornejosh

Comment: I changed it but the problem still remains  @CutePanda

Comment: @Elish in search function in while loop, after `s=frontier.remove(f)` write `print(s)` and run code, that is the source of problem `frontier.is_empty(f)` never returns True

Comment: Possible related https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-instance-8-puzzle-solvable/